# Capistrano 2 to 3: how to refactor a gem with shared recipes that uses deprecated "Capistrano::Configuration.instance(:must_exist).load do"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capistrano

I'm really digging into capistrano for the first time (instead of just using it as a magic wand) as I upgrade an app from cap 2 to cap 3. The app relies on a gem that uses the following syntax to make the recipes accessible through capistrano's special load path:

```
Capistrano::Configuration.instance(:must_exist).load do
  # tasks
end
```

This pattern is outlined in several resources I found online, such as [this (outdated) blog post](http://matthewtodd.org/2008/04/24/rails-tip-4-writing-capistrano-recipes-to-be-loaded-from-gems.html) on loading capistrano recipes from gem.

This is apparently deprecated in cap 3, as it now returns a `NoMethodError` on `.instance`. Can anyone share or point me to a resource that explains a good way to remove this block and access the tasks from the gem easily?